# Is_single not working properly in genesis

Tags: wordpress-theming, genesis

I am currently creating a child theme for my website which uses genesis as a parent theme.
Now i am making single pages as per my choosing.
So, I am removing the entry header from within html main and posting it after entry-header.
my code looks like this.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');

function gp_page_header(){
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    ?>
    <div class="post-hero" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle cover, rgba(100, 66, 255, 0.9) 15%, rgba(0, 108, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(12, 180, 206, 0.9) 85%), url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h1>' ); 
        genesis_post_info();
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
 }
```

If didn't want to create this style for homepage and should be only applied to single pages.
Here is what i am doing now.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
if(is_single()) {
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');

function gp_page_header(){
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    ?>
    <div class="post-hero" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle cover, rgba(100, 66, 255, 0.9) 15%, rgba(0, 108, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(12, 180, 206, 0.9) 85%), url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h1>' ); 
        genesis_post_info();
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
 }
}
```

But this way it doesn't work. If i use conditional tag, it isn't working.
I am confused at the moment.
Also, I am using front-page.php as template for home.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the conditional tag in the wrong place. Needs to be added after the function like this :

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'gp_page_header');

function gp_page_header(){

if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_title' );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );

    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    ?>
    <div class="post-hero" style="background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle cover, rgba(100, 66, 255, 0.9) 15%, rgba(0, 108, 255, 0.9) 50%, rgba(12, 180, 206, 0.9) 85%), url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
        <div class="wrap">
        <?php
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h1>' ); 
        genesis_post_info();
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php

  }
}
```

Based on my testing, your code needs some work.